# common value in python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

```
map1 = { 1: "Sam", 2: "Rich", 3 : "Mike", 4: "Bob", 6: "Donald"}
map2 = { 5: "Sally", 6 : "Donald", 7: "Roger", 1: "Sam"}
```

I want to print common names in both dicts, Can anyone help me out

Answer (score 5):

You can recover your values with `dict.values` and cast them to sets. This allows you to find their intersection.

```
print(set(map1.values()) & set(map2.values()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this using set

```
map1 = { 1: "Sam", 2: "Rich", 3 : "Mike", 4: "Bob", 6: "Donald"}
map2 = { 5: "Sally", 6 : "Donald", 7: "Roger", 1: "Sam"}

list(set(map1.values()).intersection(set(map2.values())))
```

it returns list with common values in both dictionary

Answer (score 0):

```
set(map1.values()).intersection(set(map2.values()))
```